# How to pass a array of strings to a function?

Tags: c, arrays, string

In the following program i just try to copy some string to the array and print it in another function.

I am getting segmentation fault .Could someone point out what i did wrong ?

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #define MAX_STR_LEN 20

  void print_str(char str[][],int count);

  int main()
  {
      char str[2][MAX_STR_LEN];
      strncpy(str[0],"hello",MAX_STR_LEN);
      strncpy(str[1],"world",MAX_STR_LEN);
      print_str(str,2);
      return 0;
  }
  void print_str(char str[][],int count)
  {
      int i;
      for(i=0;i<count;i++)
      printf("%s\n",str[i]);
  }
```

Comment: `void print_str(char str[][],int count)` --> `void print_str(char str[][MAX_STR_LEN],int count)`

Comment: If this isn't documented in whatever tutorial or book you're using, find something else. The parameter should be `char str[][MAX_STR_LEN]`. All but the most dominant dimension of an array of arrays as a parameter *must* be declared. There are probably *hundreds* of duplicates of this problem in one form or another, but generally the title is so diverse it is difficult to find them. One that is *close* would be [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486075/passing-an-array-of-strings-as-parameter-to-a-function-in-c), in particular the *second* answer.

Comment: @Naveen Kumar I'm wondering what compiler were you using - because most I know of wouldn't even compile this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to specify the **column** **size** **mandatory** when passing a **2D array** as a parameter.

So, You should declare your function like this:

```
void print_str(char str[][MAX_STR_LEN],int count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
void print_str(char str[][MAX_STR_LEN], int count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide the second dimension length in a 2-D array in C always. First dimension length is optional if you are declaring a 2-D array.